# ionic 2 cannot reading property

Tags: ionic2, pouchdb

i have a problem with a  ionic2 example,i try to call pouchdb function  whith service(birthday.service.ts) who add data with PouchDb  from my  module ( details.ts)

but i'm have this error :

EXCEPTION: Error in ./DetailsPage class DetailsPage - inline template:22:18 caused by: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined

my service : birthday.service.ts

```
 import{Injectable} from '@angular/core';
    import PouchDB from 'pouchdb'

    @Injectable()
    export class BirthdayService {

    private _db;
    private _birthdays;



    initDB(){

        this._db = new PouchDB('http://localhost:5984/birthday4'); 

    }

    add(birthday) {  
        return this._db.post(birthday);
    }
```

my module : detail.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {  NavParams,ViewController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {BirthdayService} from '../../app/services/birthday.service';

@Component({

  templateUrl: 'details.html',
  providers:[BirthdayService]
})
export class DetailsPage {

    public birthday;
    public isNew = true;
    public action = 'Add';
    public isoDate = '';

  constructor (private viewCtrl: ViewController,
        private navParams: NavParams,
        public birthdayService : BirthdayService
   ) {

   this.birthday = this.navParams.get('birthday');
   this.birthday = {Name:" "}
   this.isNew=true;

   }




     save() {
        this.birthday.Date = new Date(this.isoDate);

        if (this.isNew) {
            this.birthdayService.add(this.birthday)
                .catch(console.error.bind(console));
        } else {
            this.birthdayService.update(this.birthday)
                .catch(console.error.bind(console));
        }

        this.dismiss();
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `initDb()` function is not called, thefefore `_db` is equal to `undefined`

You could try changing `initDb()` to `ngOnInit()` after importing `OnInit` from `@angular/core` and implementing it

Comment: thank's  and how i can call the service in my module

Comment: f.e. in your constructor of component (not module), call `this.birthdayService.initDB()`

Comment: i try i have this error Property 'birthdayService' does not exist on type 'MyApp'

Comment: Is it in defined in your constructor like the code you show us? Since that class is named 'DetailsPage'

Comment: i put   this.birthdayService.onInit() in app.component.ts but when i navigate on  the pages  i have   functions of my service is undefined , i force to put this.birthdayService.onInit() on my module ( home.ts, details.ts etc )

Comment: Youre not showing the code so i cant help you. Edit the question and add your `app.module.ts` and `app.component.ts` pleass